# Mounting remote folders via afp

Tags: macos, mount

I have a problem in mounting remote folders using the AFP protocol.

In this page:

http://support.apple.com/kb/ht4538

they say - if I understood correctly - that issuing the command:

`mount_afp afp://myserver.mydomain.com/Sharepoint/Folder node`

accessing the local `node` you access the remote directory named `Folder` on the remote server.

However, when I issue that command, my OS X 10.9.2 mounts the remote `Sharepoint` and not its subfolder `Folder`. Even if I can access `Folder` also in this way, I need the local mount point to correspond exactly to the remote directory `Folder`.

What am I doing wrong?